# Django Webpack React: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: django, reactjs, npm, webpack, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to configure my react with django.

but for some reason whenever I try to `npm run start` I get this error: 
`Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In ../../node_modules/babel-preset-react/lib/index.js`
I've tried:
`npm  install @babel/preset-react` `npm install babel-preset-react --save-dev` `npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack` but did nothing.

Django version: 2.2.6

Webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
module.exports = {
  entry:  path.join(__dirname, 'assets/src/js/index'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/dist'),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'webpack-stats.json'
    }),
  ],
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: {
             presets: ['react']
          }
        },
      ],
    },
}
```

settings:

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'dist/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    }
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
      "es2015", "react"
    ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "collegeapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run start -- --watch"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": 
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": 
  },
  "homepage":
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.4.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are giving two kinds of babel for the application, I faced this complexity while configuring react base.

Based on the babel core, you need to install the babel react and its preset. Like if using **@babel/core** than, install **@babel/react and @babel/preset-react**. Make sure your react babel plugin supports the Babel core.

Remove the unnecessary plugins of babel, which confuses the web-pack which babel to use.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Fendz242 Remove the babel-core and change your .babelrc file's preset with @babel/env and @babel/preset-react

Comment: I made those changes and got this `Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'` @karthikeyan

Comment: install @babel/core then, if it is not installed it will say cannot find module

Comment: okay, I made those changes and I'm still getting  `Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions`. Do you think it maybe a version issue?

Comment: @Fendz242 go through this link https://github.com/karthikeyan71/reactBoilerPlate/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203296/discussion-between-karthi-keyan-and-fendz242).

Comment: How/where do I message you in chat? I've never used that functionality before.